# ImportError: cannot import name __VERSION__ in terraform compliance

Tags: terraform

Im trying to install terraform compliance, but when im trying to get help im getting error

{
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/terraform-compliance", line 7, in 
    from terraform_compliance.main import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/terraform_compliance/main.py", line 3, in 
    from radish.main import main as call_radish
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radish/main.py", line 12, in 
    from . import **VERSION**
ImportError: cannot import name **VERSION**

}

Comment: If you're trying to install something and it's failing you'd be better off asking in SuperUser and explain exactly what you tried to do to install the software and anything about your environment that might be causing it to fail.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i tried to install terraform compliance on ubuntu 16.04. i do it by running command sudo pip install terraform-compliance. it was installed seccesfully. but when im trying to get help by calling command : sudo terraform-compliance -h. im getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because of your `radish` (or `radish-bdd`) installation. I would uninstall/install radish and install the version that is supported by `terraform-compliance`.

The ones supported are ;

```
radish==0.1.10
radish-bdd==0.8.6
```

You can also use containerised version of `terraform-compliance`. As in described in the README.md in it's repo ;

#### Running via Docker

If terraform or feature files are in your local you need to use `-v` directive in docker like ;

```
[~] $ docker run --rm -v $PWD:/target -i -t eerkunt/terraform-compliance \
                                            -f example/example_01 \
                                            -t example/tf_files
```

or if all of your features/terraform files are in a remote git repository, you can just skip using `-v` option like ;

```
[~] $ docker run --rm -i -t eerkunt/terraform-compliance \
                            -f git:https://some.git.repository/compliance-code.git \
                            -t git:https://some.git.repository/terraform-repo.git
```

btw yes author of that tool here :) Glad to see it is being used.

Comment: Same problem reported in https://github.com/eerkunt/terraform-compliance/issues/34. It is about `radish` and `radish-bdd`. Re-installing these packages solves the problem.

Comment: The fix to this environmental problem introducted on `0.4.3` version. Please upgrade your `terraform-compliance`.

Comment: i tried to update golang and terraform with the updated version. but this is not solving the issue

Comment: You need to upgrade `terraform-compliance`, not `golang` or `terraform`. `pip install --upgrade terraform-compliance`. I highly recommend to use the docker version if you are having environmental issues.